# Can the Czech Republic revoke a UK driving licence and impose a ban?

Tags: legal, uk-citizens, driving-licenses, czech-republic

If a UK citizen residing in the Czech Republic receives a driving ban for a minor offence (not displaying a front numberplate) and he holds a UK driving licence, do the Czech authorities have have the power to revoke the UK licence and enforce the ban?

Comment: Generally speaking, only the issuing authority can revoke the license. The Czech police can fine you and impose any other penalties as per the local law. I am not sure if the UK has a reciprocal agreement over traffic violations, if it does - you may find the appropriate penalties levied to you by the competent UK authorities as well.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, not displaying the front numberplate is by no means a "minor offence". It renders all kinds of automated traffic enforcement devices (speed cameras, red light cameras at crossings, etc.) completely useless. You could thus be speeding at will and ignoring all red lights without any fines, unless the police managed to chase you down.

A driving ban ("zákaz řízení") effectively renders your driving license useless in Czechia. If you ever drive again in Czechia while under such a ban, you're commiting a crime ("maření výkonu úředního rozhodnutí) for which you can be imprisoned for up to two years (plus removed from the country and banned from re-entering).

Such a ban probably has no effect on your right to drive in the UK (there would have to be an international treaty specifying that), but IANAL.

Comment: This is the same rule followed in the USA. New Jersey cannot revoke your New York driver's license, but they *can* revoke your right to drive *in New Jersey*. As state lines cut across major urban areas all along the US east coast (and even divide neighborhoods in some areas), this is more of a barrier than you might think. On the west coast, it isn't so bad to have your driving privilege revoked somewhere (e.g. living in San Diego, CA, banned from driving in OR), but there are fewer opportunities for it to happen since most people aren't crossing state lines just to get lunch or go to work.

Answer (score 3):

Czechia has the power to ban you from driving in Czechia. But Czechia cannot revoke your foreign license.

In any case Czechia could choose to notify UK about that offense and so UK will eventually decide independently and eventually UK will revoke your license.

This depends if CZ want to do something, UK want to handle the thing, and how *minor* UK will consider the offense. Often only major offenses go to the final step, but this is very dependent on both countries, and how each countries consider problematic an offense.

Comment: I'd like to add that EU and connected European countries use several interconnected systems for sharing traffic violations, driver's licences and vehicle information, so it is possible for Czech police to check your driver's licence online and your violations are shared to your home country. What is or isn't done specifically I don't know (as it changes overtime based on bureaucracy).